# How to Fill a Matrix based on values X and Y

Tags: r, matrix

This is the original matrix if it helps. I am trying to do part A.

[image]

I am completely new to R, like 6 days new. Our instructor just gave us these questions with almost no R explanation. Is there a way to fill the matrix in the image in a more of an qutomatic way, rather than doing everything one by one.
So far all I did is:

```
x_and_y_val <- matrix(c(3,4,2,2,1,3,-1,1,0, 0),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(x_and_y_val) <- c("x","y")
rownames(x_and_y_val) <- c("","", "", "", "")
x_and_y_val <- as.table(x_and_y_val)
# original matrix with x and y
x_and_y_val

#find the averages of Xs and Ys
x_avg <-
y_avg <-
```

I will then find their averages complute all the values and eventaully create a new matrix of size 5x6. But I have a very strong feeling that there can be a better more efficient way. If you know how, can you explain it to me. Or direct me to a source that does?

Stay safe and Healthy!

Answer (score 0):

Beginning to learn R can feel daunting for sure! There are two popular schools of learning R: `base` and `tidyverse`. There is too much to cover about the differences between `base` and `tidy verse` in a SO post, so I'll put a link to [Hadley Wickham's textbook](https://r4ds.had.co.nz) on writing R tidyverse code. I'll provide both solutions here:

**Base:**

To make the data frame, you can use this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(3,2,1,-1,0),
  y = c(4,3,2,1,0)
)

   x y
1  3 4
2  2 3
3  1 2
4 -1 1
5  0 0
```

Then to get the averages, you can use this:

```
x_avg <- mean(x)
y_avg <- mean(y)
```

**Tidyverse:**

To make the data frame, you can use this:

```
df <- tibble(
  x = c(3,2,1,-1,0),
  y = c(4,3,2,1,0)
)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     4
2     2     3
3     1     2
4    -1     1
5     0     0
```

Then to get the averages, you can use this:

```
df %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), 
                   .fns = mean,
                   .names = "mean_{.col}"))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  mean_x mean_y
   <dbl>  <dbl>
1      1      2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful. I think I'll eventually have to learn tidyverse but at the moment base feels more natural. Whoever you are, I hope you have a great day or night depending on the time.

Comment: No worries, if this answer helped, please feel free to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to stick with matrices, which is perfectly fine (and faster) in your case, because you calculate numbers. `data.frame`s are needed if you also have strings and other stuff in your data.

I would build up the initial matrix column-wise and use the `dimnames=` argument. `dimnames=` wants a list of row and column names. Since we don't really need row names here we may use `NULL` to use the default. For the column names we should use [valid names](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html).

```
m <- matrix(c(3, 2, 1, -2, 0,
              4, 2, 3, 1, 0), ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("x", "y")))

m
#       x y
# [1,]  3 4
# [2,]  2 2
# [3,]  1 3
# [4,] -2 1
# [5,]  0 0
```

Based on the initial matrix we can do calculations, and add them as columns using `cbind`.

```
x.dm <- m[,"x"] - mean(m[,"x"])  ## "dm" because of de-meaned
x.dm.sq=x.dm^2
y.dm <- m[,"y"] - mean(m[,"y"])
y.dm.sq=y.dm^2
p.dm=x.dm.sq*y.dm.sq
m <- cbind(m, x.dm, x.dm.sq, y.dm, y.dm.sq, p.dm)
m
#       x y x.dm x.dm.sq y.dm y.dm.sq  p.dm
# [1,]  3 4  2.2    4.84    2       4 19.36
# [2,]  2 2  1.2    1.44    0       0  0.00
# [3,]  1 3  0.2    0.04    1       1  0.04
# [4,] -2 1 -2.8    7.84   -1       1  7.84
# [5,]  0 0 -0.8    0.64   -2       4  2.56
```

For the column sums we may use `colSums`.

```
colSums(m)
#            x            y         x.dm      x.dm.sq         y.dm      y.dm.sq         p.dm 
# 4.000000e+00 1.000000e+01 2.220446e-16 1.480000e+01 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+01 2.980000e+01
```

**Note:** The weird notation comes from the very small value in `x.dm` which is probably due to rounding issues. See [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/6574038). `zapsmall` will convert them to zero.

```
zapsmall(colSums(m))
#   x       y    x.dm x.dm.sq    y.dm y.dm.sq    p.dm 
# 4.0    10.0     0.0    14.8     0.0    10.0    29.8
```

Comment: Thank you this is also very helpful. I feel a little bit more optimistic about the remining 10 hours of this homework.

Comment: You're welcome @YükselPolatAkbıyık , you will master this in less time!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version (more simple for a beginner IMHO):

```
#impute base vectors x and y
x <- c(3,2,1,-1,0)
y <- c(4,2,3,1,0)

#calculate their means
x_mean <- mean(x)
y_mean <- mean(y)

#determine the remaining columns of the table
x-x_mean
(x-x_mean)^2
y-y_mean
(x-x_mean)*(y-y_mean)

#summarize
table <- cbind(x,
      y,
      x-x_mean,
      (x-x_mean)^2,
      y-y_mean,
      (x-x_mean)*(y-y_mean)
      )
#specify the header
colnames(table) <- c("x","y","x-x_mean","(x-x_mean)^2","y-y_mean","(x-x_mean)(y-y_mean)")

table

      x y x-x_mean (x-x_mean)^2 y-y_mean (x-x_mean)(y-y_mean)
[1,]  3 4        2            4        2                    4
[2,]  2 2        1            1        0                    0
[3,]  1 3        0            0        1                    0
[4,] -1 1       -2            4       -1                    2
[5,]  0 0       -1            1       -2                    2
```